# SQLite Add Row To Table With *ONLY* One Autoincrement Row

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, auto-increment

I wanted to know how does one add a row to a table that has exclusively one column that has the autoincrement flag set, such as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [Individual]([Id_Individual] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT FAIL AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL UNIQUE ON CONFLICT FAIL);
```

I know that I can add a row such as below, but the problem is that this overrides the AUTOINCREMENT feature.

```
INSERT INTO Individual (Id_Individual) VALUES (100);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was tying the question, I found the answer:

```
INSERT INTO Individual DEFAULT VALUES;
```